# Автоматическое форматирование текста в Excel 2003

Tags: форматирование, excel, текст

Я недавно на форуме, не знаю, могу ли я задать вопрос по Excel здесь? 
В общем, у меня есть большой список фамилий и цифры напротив каждой, мне нужно выделить одним цветом цифры до 20, другим цветом 20-35, и выше 35 третьим. И еще изменять шрифт цифр на этих интервалах. Как это сделать?

Помогите, пожалуйста.

P.S. Excel 2003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формат ячеек можно изменять с помощью *условного форматирования* (УФ)

В Excel-2003 в УФ можно задавать не более трех условий.

Формулы для первого и третьего диапазонов (принимаем размещение чисел в столбце B):

```
=B1<20

=B1>35
```

Если первое условие задавать для среднего диапазона, то придется прописывать границы диапазона:

```
=ЕСЛИ(B1>=20;B1<=35)
=ЕСЛИ(И(B1>=20;B1<=35);1)
=И(B1>=20;B1<=35)
```

Первая формула из этих трех лучше - при невыполнении первого условия второе не проверяется.

Но если условия задавать последовательно, нижнюю границу можно не проверять (она проверяется в первом условии):

```
=B1<=35
```

Т.к. под условия попадают все числовые значения, можно ограничиться только двумя условиями - изначально залить диапазон одним цветом.
В УФ можно менять не только цвет ячейки, но и цвет, вид, размер шрифта, обрамление ячейки и другие форматы.

Comment: Спасибо большое, попробую.